# ElementTree/TidyHTMLTreeBuilder mucks up trailing spaces in my text

Tags: python, xml

I am working on an application written in Python that accepts HTML from a browser hosted HTML editor. The application loads this HTML into a ElementTree document for processing using TidyHTMLTreeBuilder as a parser. The problem I am finding is that the XML document sees fit to reorganise the nodes such that any trailing spaces on a node (say, SPAN) are added to the tail of the node. This is not so bad except that the spaces are added to a higher level node. The processing I am doing requires uses the node's CSS styles to identify text sections, thus moving that space causes problems.

Here is an actual example:

An excerpt from the HTML posted:

```
<td style="width: 4.7729in; padding-top: 0.0000in; padding-left: 0.0556in; padding-bottom: 0.0000in; padding-right: 0.0556in; border-width: 1px; border-color: #FDD87B; border-style: solid;">
  <p style="padding-top: 0.0833in; padding-bottom: 0.0833in;">
    <span style="font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Tahoma,sans-serif; font-size: 10.0pt;">
      <span id="DM_57134" class="defn_meaning">
        <span id="DM_57133" class="defn_meaning">
          <span id="DM_57273" class="defn_meaning">Sally sells sea shells </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <a class="popup" href="ID_57274" target="_blank">
        <span id="DM_57134_1" class="defn_meaning">
          <span id="DM_57133_1" class="defn_meaning">
            <span id="DM_57273_1" class="defn_meaning">by the sea shore</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </p>
</td>
```

The tree gets loaded as follows:

```
[td  "\n" (
  [p   (
    [span   (
        [span id="DM_57134" 
            (
                [span id="DM_57133" 
                    (
                        [span id="DM_57273" "Sally sells sea shells" ()]
                    )
                 ]
             ) tail=" "
         ]
         [a   (
             [span id="DM_57134_1" 
                 (
                     [span id="DM_57133_1" 
                         (
                             [span id="DM_57273_1" "by the sea shore" ()]
                         )
                     ]
                 )
             ])
         ])
       ]) tail="\n"
     ]) tail="\n"]) 
   tail="\n"]
```

As you can see, the trailing space at the ed of "Sally sells sea shells" used to belong to the DM_57273 node but ended up being attached to the DM_57134 node.

So the questions are:

1. Why is it doing this?
2. Is there a way I can prevent the trailing spaces being handled this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that happens, but an alternative to TidyHTMLTreeBuilder + ElementTree that might work fine for you is [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). For example:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(<html>)
>>> soup.find(id='DM_57273')
<span id="DM_57273" class="defn_meaning">Sally sells sea shells </span>
>>> soup.find(id='DM_57273').string
u'Sally sells sea shells '
```

As it can be seen, for the same example as in the question, the trailing whitespace is still part of the tag.